# a problem after SUSE 11 password changed

Tags: linux, suse

I trying to change my password in SUSE 11.

I started with fail-save mode and `init=/bin/bash` to boot options, then I want to change my pass, I face this problem:

After that I research then Internet and used `mount -o remount,rw /` to diminish this error, then the password changed succeeds, but now When I reboot system, I face this problem:

```
Activating swap-devices in /etc/fstab...
[  351.882634] Adding 1124588k swap on /dev/sda1. Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1124588k
                                                                     failed
blogd: no message logging because /var file system is not accessible
...
fsck failed. Please repair manually and reboot. The root
file system is currently mounted read-only. To remount it
read-write do:

    bash# mount -n -o remount,rw /

Attention: Only CONTROL-D will rebot the system in this
maintenance mode. shutdown or reboot will not work.

Give root password for login:
(repair filesystem) #
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I solve that

with the method with had explained in:

[System in read-only mode CTRL-D ? – Artica Proxy](http://artica-proxy.com/system-in-read-only-mode-ctrl-d/)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please describe the essence of the solution here. We don't like link-only answers here since links tend to break after a while.